# Need a shell script for the following scenario

Tags: shell, scripting

I have multiple log files in a directory /home/user/ with pattern x.log, y.log, z.log :
content of files are :

```
error

pass

fail 

executed

not executed

Summary:
test 1 

test 2 

test 3

Finished in 2682 min 43.9 sec.

done

completed
```

i want output in a new single file from multiple log files as:

```
Summary:

test 1 

test 2 

test 3

Finished in 2682 min 43.9 sec.

Summary:

test 1 

test 2 

test 3

Finished in 2682 min 43.9 sec.

Summary:

test 1 

test 2 

test 3

Finished in 2682 min 43.9 sec.
```

Can you help me out with shell script

Comment: What shell? What have you tried?

Comment: StackOverflow is not an appropriate forum for "please write a script for me that does X" requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '/Summary/ {run=1} run==1 {print} /Finished/ {run=0}' *.log > log.agr
```

This will take the contents of every file ending with `.log`, start writing to log.agr when it finds a line containing `Summary`, and then skip lines after a line containing `Finished`. It'll repeat that through the entire contents of all the `*.log` files.

Comment: Thanks , but i need content from each log file to be written in new file between string "Summary" and "Finished".

Comment: i tried this : sed -n '/^Summary$/,/^Finished/{$d;p;}' lnxapp101.log > output.txt , but it is creating emply log file

Comment: @user1711414 absolutely!

Comment: This could be written: `'/Summary/{run=1}run;/Finished/{run=0}'`, or even just `'/Summary/,/Finished/'`